# switches for shell script

Tags: linux, shell

what is the best way to implement switches [ex: -m] for shell scripts?
I can do it via the switch case statement. But i am curious to know is there any other standard way to get all the arguments into a variable via a switch. 
        Ex:
        -m A1 A2 -c c1 c2

So that,
        M[] can take -m 
        and C[] can all take -c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best known way is to use `getopts`, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

An example :

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: don't forget some things : 1) if you use multiple getopts (ex: you have several function each using it) you need to add before the while loop : `OPTIND=1`  (so that it start at the 1st argument). And 2) after the while loop :  `shift $((OPTIND-1))` (so that your script/function can then know how many arguments were processed by getops and have "at hand" the remaining arguments). I always add both to each getopts while....done loop. and 3) in the above, there is also the special case:  `:)  echo "error: the option -$OPTARG needs an argument and none was provided." ; exit 1 ;;`